# align ul inside li in one line

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm trying to make some li's work and can't figure out the following:
1) for example:

```
<ul>
<li> very long element</li>
<li> short </li>
</ul>
```

is it possible with CSS to make the second li element to have width equall to text inside it?
Apparently its width will be equall to the width of the first element

2) Can I arrange my li and ul in the following way (i write it without formatting so that it displays the way i would like it to be):

|ul|

|li|top1 |ul| |li|sub1|/li| |li|sub2|/li| |/ul|

|li|top2 |ul| |li|sub3|/li| |li|sub4|/li| |/ul|

|/ul|

in other words, have CSS which would align inside particular  li    ul and it's li  in the same line with it?

Regards,
Denis.

Comment: do you already have some css you can show here?

Comment: These are two separate questions. Consider moving the first to a new question, because the title and the already given answer address the second.

Comment: @NGLN i think already given answer does not answer the second, but rather fist question. So, it should be like http://jsfiddle.net/BWZfr/1/ but sub items in the same line as item one. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this, I'm not sure:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>item one</li>
    <li>item two two two two two</li>
    <li>item three three</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li { float: left; clear: left; margin-bottom: 10px; background: #ccc }
```

**Looks like**

http://jsfiddle.net/BWZfr/

And for your second question... maybe you mean something like http://jsfiddle.net/BWZfr/1/ ?

Comment: might want to repost your jsfiddle link

Comment: @Chris  Thank you for your help. yes, your second example looks like what I need, but I want these sub to be in the same line as parent li? is it possible?

Comment: I think this is what you want. I couldn't figure out how to do it without an extra div. http://jsfiddle.net/BWZfr/11/

Comment: @chris that's exactly it. The point is that the ul-li structure is generated by CMS, co I can't really put in another div, that's why i'm trying to make it work only with ul/li CSS.

Comment: @chris i checked the output I work with and luckily it does have <a></a> tag inside first-level li, so your solution works perfectly for me! Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

I think this will answer both questions.  Here is the simplest way I can achieve this.  The list will stay all in one single line while the markup is still semantically correct.  I added padding just so to keep the items evenly spaced.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>List 1:1</li>
    <li>List 1:2</li>
    <li>List 1:3</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>List 2:1</li>
            <li>List 2:2</li>
            <li>List 2:3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>List 3:1</li>
    <li>List 3:2</li>
    <li>List 3:3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul { list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
li { display:inline; float:left; padding:0 10px; margin:0; }
```

Comment: i'm sorry, not exactly. That's what i'd like to do, but without extra div http://jsfiddle.net/BWZfr/11/